# how to add wamp feature to lamp

Tags: linux, ubuntu, webserver

I am used to do web development using wampserver in windows but recently I wanted to move to Linux and I am using LAMP now but I found that some useful feature in wampserver are not available in LAMP like :

- switch online/offline
- stop all services
- restart all services
- start all services

How can I add those feature to Lamp especially switch online/offline?

**edit : What i mean with switch online/offline is to give access to everyone or only localhost**

Comment: What's wrong with `service < option > | --status-all | [ service_name [ command | --full-restart ] ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how:

```
switch online/offline - sudo /etc/init.d/httpd stop|start
stop all services     - sudo /etc/init.d/httpd stop
restart all services  - sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart
start all services    - sudo /etc/init.d/httpd start

put all that script in a shell script and run it as 
 sudo sh ./start_services (args)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean with "Adding ... to LAMP" that you switch these things on/off via a web interface. This is normally not available as the user as which the Apache runs under Linux doesn't have the rights to execute these task.

It is possible to circumvent these restrictions, but since they involve security risks you will not find them in a normal LAMP setup¹.

You should use the normal commands for controlling services on Ubuntu: `start`, `stop`, `restart` (as `root`/using `sudo`).

¹ <sub>In Windows these kind of security risks come standard out of the box</sub>

Answer (score 0):

One way you can accomplish this is by using LXD.

I use Ubuntu as LXD development uses Ubuntu as it's reference OS.

So... Install Ubuntu + LXD at host/machine level.

Create LXD containers for your sites or collections of sites.

Then container access can be managed in various ways...

1. If you set no public IP for a given container, then people can only access the container by **ssh into machine** + **lxc exec $container bash**.
2. Setup public IPs for your containers + setup ssh keys in each container.

I host many client sites in many containers, so I tend to use the latter approach + also setup MySecureShell as the SFTP server, so people can access their sites in various ways.

Also using the latter approach, since each container has a public IP, free https://LetsEncrypt.org SSL certs can be used to wrap all sites, production + development + staging.